# How to show a view through protocol?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to detective networking state, when networking state changed, show a error view in current controller. But there is a problem by using protocol.
Here is the codes:

```
private func networkingDetection() {
    //This is the detective method in appdelegate
    try! reachability.startNotifier()

    reachability.whenReachable = { [weak self] _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.currentViewController().hideNetworkingErrorView()
        }
    }

    reachability.whenUnreachable = { [weak self] _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.currentViewController().showNetworkingErrorView()
        }
    }

}
```

And here is the protocol

```
protocol NetworkingErrorProtocol {
 // I want to show the default view if there is no networkingErrorView, and
when declare a custom view in controller, show the custom view.
//var networkingErrorView: UIView? { get }

func showNetworkingErrorView()
func hideNetworkingErrorView()

}


extension UIViewController: NetworkingErrorProtocol {
func showNetworkingErrorView() {

}
func hideNetworkingErrorView() {

}
```

}

Anyone can tell me how to figure it out? It's really makes me crazy.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: why did you use protocol instead of NSNotification centre ?

Comment: What is `currentViewController()` defined as? `UIViewController`?

Comment: I agree. `NSNotificationCenter` would be a much cleaner way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your setup is that conforming `UIViewController` to your protocol does not allow you to receive that call in your subclass. If you try to override the protocol function in your subclass you will get a compiler error: `Declarations from extensions cannot be overridden yet`

First off, a note about NotificationCenter. If you need multiple parts of your app to be notified of the change that would be a good way to go. If you only need to tell one controller, this is a classic usage for a delegate.

Here are two ways to get the desired functionality: using the delegate pattern and without.
Let's say `Manager` is the class where the monitoring is happening:

Using a delegate pattern

```
class Manager {

    weak var networkDelegate : NetworkStatusListener?

    func monitorNetworkStatus() {

        var reachable = true;
        if reachable {
            // We can call the delegate directly
            networkDelegate?.networkStatusChanged(.connected)
        }
        else {
            networkDelegate?.networkStatusChanged(.disconnected)
        }
    }
}
```

And the same Manager without a delegate pattern. This would be the simplest fix for your current implementation issue.

```
class Manager {

    func currentViewController() -> UIViewController  { return vc }

    func monitorNetworkStatus() {
        var maybeAtListener = currentViewController()

        // DON't SHIP THIS, but it can be helpful during development to make sure you didn't forget to conform one of your classes
        assert(maybeAtListener is NetworkStatusListener, "Oops, did you mean to conform \(currentVC) to NetworkStatusListener")

        var reachable = true;
        if reachable {
            // We can't be sure the controller conforms to the protocol but we can try
            (maybeAtListener as? NetworkStatusListener)?.networkStatusChanged(.connected)
        }
        else {
            (maybeAtListener as? NetworkStatusListener)?.networkStatusChanged(.connected)
        }
    }
}
```

Then for your view controller

```
class MyController : UIViewController, NetworkStatusDelegate {

    func networkStatusChanged(_ status: NetworkStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .connected:
            // Normal UI
            break
        case .disconnected:
            // No network connect
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, not directly related to your question but for this example I used a slightly different approach to the protocol design that can be helpful for "status" oriented protocols. Having multiple functions can often become a little more tedious to conform to as protocols get larger.

```
enum NetworkStatus {
    case connected
    case disconnected
}
protocol NetworkStatusListener : class {
    func networkStatusChanged(_ status: NetworkStatus)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using reachability class's NSNotificationCenter

add this in  appdelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions if you want for whole app

OR add in your specific viewcontroller if you want this in specific Viewcontroller

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:Selector(("checkForReachability:")), name: NSNotification.Name.reachabilityChanged, object: nil);
 let reachability: Reachability = Reachability.forInternetConnection();
 reachability.startNotifier();
```

This method called while network state changed .

```
func checkForReachability(notification:NSNotification)
        {

            let networkReachability = notification.object as! Reachability;
            _ = networkReachability.currentReachabilityStatus()
            // do yor additional work here
    }
```